# Update php query limit whit js when load more

Tags: php, javascript

Hi I'm working on a reverse infinite scroll for a private message module.

The think is everything is working okay, my only problem is that I am not being able to update the limit of the query I am using. 
The thing is a create the max and limit in php:

```
$max = mysql_num_rows($q_mensajes_contador_cargar);

$limit = $max-5;
```

Then when I use the infinite scroll I send the max and limit this way

```
$.ajax({
    url: "formularios/cargar_mensajes.php?id=<? echo $id_receptor;?>&limite=<? echo $limit;?>",
    success: function (html) {
        if (html) {
            $("#profile-feed-1").prepend(html);
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
        } else {
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
        }
    }
});
```

The thing is when I get this values in cargar_mensajes.php it just works once cause it is continually updating the same thing over and over, I want it to detect when it printed the next messages and update the query to show more or not show more depending in how many times it updates.
Sorry for my english...
Any advice, my js level is basic and I am sure that the way I am thinking this must not be the correct, just would like to know how can I achieve this.

Thank you!

Comment: Your JavaScript function is inside a php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the limit using PhP, so it never changes.

What you could do is :

```
var limit = <?php echo $limit; ?>
... 
url: "formularios/cargar_mensajes.php?id=<? echo $id_receptor;?>&limite=" + limit,
success: function(html)
{
    limit = limit + 5; // (Or -5, or whatever you need.)
```

Tell me if you need a more detailled code.